# Placing an object in a tub changes the weight of the tub?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, buoyancy

Suppose you have a tub filled with water and it rests on a scale so you can measure the weight. If you place an object in the tub, will the reading on the scale change?

Clearly if the object sinks to the bottom, it exerts a normal force on the tub and so the scale reading increases. If the object floats, it is not obvious to me what will happen. And I suspect the reading on the scale will change depending on how much of the object is submerged.

Sorry if this is a silly question.

Comment: By "filled with water" do you mean that any rise in water level will overflow?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the reading on the scale goes up by approximately the weight of the object, even if the object is floating. When you place the object in the tub, the water level rises. This increases the water pressure at the bottom of the tub. That pressure is what the tub feels, so from tub's point of view, it's as if the water became heavier and the scale reading goes up.

The amount the scale reading goes up is very close to the object's weight, but slightly less. That's because the floating object feels a small buoyant force from the air as well as a buoyant force from the water. The scale reading goes up only by the amount of buoyant force from the water.

Comment: Thats what I guessed: the scale reading goes up by the weight of the water displaced. But I don't understand why?

Comment: Because the water level rises, increasing the pressure.

Comment: Yes it goes up because the pressure is increased, but why by that amount? Sorry this is not obvious to me.

Comment: If the buoyant force is $W$, then the object pushes down on the water with a force $W$ by Newton's third law. The water is not accelerating, so the net force on it is zero, so the force upward on the water from the tub must increase by $W$. So the force from pressure on the tub increases by $W$ by Newton's third law.